# Sobre escritura de datos en array de objetos (Java Script)

Tags: javascript, array, objeto

introducir el código aquísoy nuevo en Js, quiero cargar un array con objetos mediante un prompt. Intenté con dos elementos, al mostrarlos tanto el primer elemento como el segundo contienen la información cargada del segundo elemento. Adjunto una imagen del código, no se si es la manera de hacerlo. Muchas gracias.

```
alumno = {
nombre : "",
asistencias : [],
situacion: false
};

alumnos = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++){
  alumno.nombre = prompt(`Alumno ${i} ¿Como te llamas?`);
  alumnos[i]=alumno;
}

for (let i=0;i<alumnos.length;i++){
  alert(alumnos[i].nombre)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba con:

```javascript
let alumnos = [];

for(let i=0; i<2; i++){
    let nombre = prompt(`Alumno ${i} ¿Cómo te llamas?`);
  alumnos.push({
    nombre: nombre,
    asistencias: [],
    situacion: false
  });
}

for(let i=0; i<alumnos.length; i++){
    alert(alumnos[i].nombre);
}
```

Comment: Hola sgb004 me funcionó a la perfección, muchas gracias!. Perdón por la imagen, ya edité la publicación y la cambie por el código. Es mi primera pregunta en el foro.

Comment: Ayudaría mucho si editas y agregas una explicación a tu código, puedes consultar [answer]

Comment: Me pareció un ejemplo tan burdo que creo no requiere sobre explicación